# Create a filled curve with python

Tags: python, bezier-curves

I can make a curve with python, but I'd like to convert that curve into a renderable tube. In blender 2.6 and up, I can just select the "Fill Mode" of the curve as "full", change the "Preview U" and "Bevel" properties, and I haz a tube.

How I can I do that in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This script will add a new bezier curve, and set its bevel and resolution properties:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_curve_add()

c = bpy.context.object

c.data.resolution_u     = 24     # Preview U
c.data.fill_mode        = 'FULL' # Fill Mode ==> Full
c.data.bevel_depth      = 0.02   # Bevel Depth
c.data.bevel_resolution = 4      # Bevel Resolution
```

On a more general note, Blender can help you find the Python API commands and properties for doing most anything. When you hover with your mouse cursor on a property in the UI, you'll see a tooltip message, that includes the Python API at the bottom (in the example below I placed the cursor over the Bevel Depth property):

[image: Tooltip]

Also, the [online API documentation](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/) is your best friend. There's a convenient search box on the left menu, that will get you all kinds of useful stuff if you type in "[curve bevel](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/search.html?q=curve%20bevel&check_keywords=yes&area=default)", for instance.

Comment: @nbubis - Need to note that I fixed a little bug there with the curve object reference